# A logarithm base that converges to the sum of the harmonic series at infinity?

Tags: calculus

This is my first question on this platform, so i'm sorry if my writing & explanations are a bit off.

It is known that:
$$
\lim_{N \to \infty} \left (  \left (\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{1}{n} \right ) - \ln(N) \right )  = 0.5772156649... = \gamma
$$
The definition of the ***Euler–Mascheroni*** constant.

I will define the following function:
$$
f(x) = \lim_{N \to \infty} \left (  \left (\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{1}{n} \right ) - \log_{x}(N) \right )
$$

My question is, is there a well-known constant for $x$ that satisfies $f(x)=0$ ?

From simple numerical evaluation, I was able to see that $x \approx 2.563$, but I am not capable of even thinking if there is an analytic way to solve this.

Comment: What equation are you solving? The one with $f(x)$ on the left just looks like a definition of $f(x)$. If it is, it's "solved" for every $x$ in the domain of $f$ by definition; if it isn't, we have no idea what $f$ is and can't solve the equation.

Comment: What do you mean by solve? Do you mean that the limit is finite?

Comment: $$\underset{N\to \infty }{\text{lim}}\left(\sum _{n=1}^N \frac{1}{n}-\log _x(N)\right)$$ is $-\infty$ if $0<x<e,x\ne1$ and is $+\infty$ if $x>e$

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I have edited the original question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $ N>1$ and $ x\ne 1$,

$$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^N\frac 1n-\log_x(N)=$$

$$\sum_{n=1}^N\frac 1n-\ln(N)+\ln(N)(1-\frac{1}{\ln(x)})$$

the limit when $ N\to+\infty $ is infinite.

Comment: I was missing brackets around the sum of the harmonic series. the $ log_{x}(N) $ is not part of the sum

Comment: @BarYamin It does not matter. What is written here is correct.

Comment: @Gary, I am confused then.
There is a clear definition of the euler-mascheroni constant, which originates from $f(e)$

Comment: @BarYamin The limit is infinity iff $x\neq e$. $f(e)=\gamma$ and $f(x)=\pm\infty$ if $x\neq e$.

Comment: @Gary how can this be proved?

Comment: Can you show that $$
\left( {\sum\limits_{n = 1}^N {\frac{1}{n}} } \right) - \log _x N = \left( {\left( {\sum\limits_{n = 1}^N {\frac{1}{n}} } \right) - \log N} \right) + \left( {1 - \frac{1}{{\log x}}} \right)\log N?
$$

Comment: @Gary got it, thank you very much!